# Ubuntu 22.04 cannot install nvidia-utils-515 and nvidia-cuda-toolkit

Tags: nvidia, cuda

While installing cuda driver and cuda-toolkit from Ubuntu repositories on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS/desktop variant and I have serious packages conflict issue. I can either have nvidia-utils OR nvidia-cuda-toolkit. But I need both nvcc and nvidia-smi.

Driver installation:

```
# ubuntu-drivers devices
# sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Provides me with recommended nvidia-driver-515 package together with nvidia-utils-515 (and nvidia-smi).

Toolkit installation:

```
# apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

removes nvidia-utils-515 package!

No way around it, as further reinstall attempt on nvidia-utils-515 removes toolikt package!

```
# apt install nvidia-utils-515
(...)
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libcuinj64-11.5 libnvidia-compute-495 libnvidia-compute-510 libnvidia-ml-dev nsight-systems nsight-systems-target nvidia-cuda-dev nvidia-cuda-toolkit nvidia-profiler
  nvidia-visual-profiler
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-compute-515 nvidia-utils-515
(...)
```

How to have complete cuda installation with smi and nvcc without using nvidia repository?

**UPDATE**: Temporary pure ubuntu repo-dependent solution (but you end up with older driver):
Until toolkit update in ubuntu repositories (nvidia-cuda-toolkit depending on libnvidia-compute-510), one can donwgrade to nvidia-driver-510. This does not conflict with nvidia-cuda-toolkit.
Also, as toolkit spreads files among many other directories, one can create fake cud dir.
Current makeshift solution look like this:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
apt install nvidia-driver-510
update-initramfs -u
reboot
apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
mkdir /usr/local/cuda
cd /usr/local/cuda
ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/bin bin
ln -s /usr/include include
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu lib64
ln -s /usr/share share
```

Comment: The utils and driver packages each contain nvidia-smi, and so are marked as a conflict. What executable(s) are you actually missing (nvcc is only in the toolkit).

Comment: Both nvidia-driver-515 or nvidia-utils-515 reinstall remove nvidia-cuda-toolkit, so no nvidia-smi for me if I have toolkit installed. Looks like a problem with nvidia-cuda-toolkit depending on libnvidia-compute-510 instead of libnvidia-compute-515.

Comment: The dependncies have always been a nightmare, so I use use the .run script from Nvidia, reject any offer of the Nvidia driver, and try to override any system area for the installation of libraries and binaries. This results in the nvidia-smi in /usr/bin from the nvidia-driver install, and the nvcc + others into the /usr/local/cuda-11.7 (make /usr/local user writeable so you could run the .run script without sudo, then move the cuda-11.7 where you want it. Restore the permissions on /usr/local.

Comment: after browsing SO, asking google for the answer finally stumbled on this. Thank you for the update. For me it was the steps 2 and 3...

apt install nvidia-driver-510
update-initramfs -u

thank you for the update really appreciate this!

Comment: The actual solution  involves *not* using `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` for drivers above 495 (Cuda 11.5) but rather using metapackage `cuda-x-x` to install the respective version ... at the end  it seems the `PATH` needs to be set e.g. `PATH="/usr/local/cuda-11.7/bin:$PATH"` .. it seems it also goes in the CUDA_HOME variable but the jury is still out on that

Answer (score 5):

##### Solution

Currently (Sep.8 2022) you can download the CUDA toolkit on the NVIDIA website (regarding your Ubuntu version, can also switch to other systems):

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=22.04&target_type=deb_local

instead of downloading the driver and toolkit separately with `apt`.

##### Procedure

1. To do this, you need to firstly remove the existing driver (510 or 515), and/or the toolkit (may have been installed from `apt`), depending on where are you struggling at. Note that `nvidia-utils-yourversion` should not be removed;
2. Follow the instructions in the link above (strictly follow instructions when rebooting at the last step, otherwise `nvidia-smi` tools cannot work properly);
3. Finally, for me it is a necessity to manually create a symlink for the CUDA toolkits with

```
    sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-11.7/bin/* /usr/bin
```

(Note: Here I am installing ver 11.7. The version name in the directory should be modified according to the version you are installing)

Then both `nvidia-smi` and `nvcc -V` works.

##### Remarks

Following this method, `nvcc -V` gives

> nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
> Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
> Built on Wed_Jun__8_16:49:14_PDT_2022
> Cuda compilation tools, release 11.7, V11.7.99
> Build cuda_11.7.r11.7/compiler.31442593_0

and `nvidia-smi` gives

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.65.01    Driver Version: 515.65.01    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   43C    P3    N/A /  N/A |      5MiB /  6144MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

CUDA version and driver versions are compatible.

Comment: do linux-headers version matter at all (command `uname -r`)?

Comment: nvidia-smi works without cuda

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, I had the 515 driver and could install nvidia-cuda-toolkit.
The post-installation guide from [nvidia](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#recommended-post) helped: if you compile and run the *deviceQuery* script (after creating the symbolic links), it throws an error `system has unsupported display driver / cuda driver combination.`
Install the 510 drivers, reboot, and voila! And then Blender works with GPU!

Symbolic link to the folder:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/ /usr/local/cuda
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions of @Lukas the Silvan and @yongxi work on some but not all systems. Therefore, I'm adding a more general solution which explains the approach:

Here's a generic solution *independent* from the cuda version.

1. The goal to set the correct path to the cuda library which is called `libcudart.so.<version number>`.
2. We find this path by `sudo find / -name 'libcudart.so.<version number>'`
3. We must add the path to the folder (not to the file) containing `libcudart.so.<version number>` in a profile script, e.g. `.bashrc`:

   `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path to libcudart.so file>:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

The point is that the  varies greatly between systems.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem on Ubuntu Server 22.04 / Dell R730/Tesla P100:

First I started with a higher version of driver and CUDA installation from:
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=22.04&target_type=deb_local

Here is the code I used to install both supplied from the above download page:

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu2204.pin

sudo mv cuda-ubuntu2204.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600

wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/12.2.1/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-2-local_12.2.1-535.86.10-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-2-local_12.2.1-535.86.10-1_amd64.deb
sudo cp /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-2-local/cuda-*-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y install cuda
```

---

cuda is installed and shows under:  `cd /usr/local/cuda` but `nvcc --version` says:

```
Command 'nvcc' not found, but can be installed with:
```

To fix this:

It looks like, cuda is not in $PATH, check it with `echo $PATH`

```
/home/cem/anaconda3/bin:/home/cem/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

We will edit the $PATH

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Copy this to the end.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH
```

Save and exit (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>)

Update the source.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Check if it worked.

```
which nvcc
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc

nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jul_11_02:20:44_PDT_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.2, V12.2.128
Build cuda_12.2.r12.2/compiler.33053471_0
```

Yes, it worked, but still:

```
import torch
print(torch.__version__)
print(torch.cuda.is_available())

2.0.1
False
```

Uninstall torch-vision and reinstall it.

```
pip uninstall torch torchvision torchaudio
pip install torch torchvision torchaudio -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu122/torch_stable.html
```

Reboot the machine.

```
sudo reboot now
```

Check if it is is installed.

```
print("Torch version:",torch.__version__)
print("CUDA version used by PyTorch:", torch.version.cuda)
print("CUDA available:", torch.cuda.is_available())
print("Number of CUDA devices:", torch.cuda.device_count())
print("Current CUDA device:", torch.cuda.current_device())

Torch version: 2.0.1+cu117
CUDA version used by PyTorch: 11.7
CUDA available: True
Number of CUDA devices: 1
Current CUDA device: 0
```

Tadaaa!

nvidia-smi cuda version is not matching nvcc --version ????

`nvidia-smi` shows the highest version of CUDA that can be supported by the nvidia driver.