# Problem with nvidia-smi, nvtop, nvcc [Ubuntu 22.04] (hybrid GPU)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04

I know that there are thousands posts on how to install drivers, I tried several but nothing helps.

Let me describe how I got to my problem. My GPU is NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile CUDA available

1. I purged my current (at the time) driver using `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`  pic (I took the image from Additional Drivers) (was't grayed out at the time) -->
   [driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRUNf.png)
2. Ran several commands after that `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get autoremove`
3. Did `apt search nvidia-driver`
   I had 20+ options there. 470, 535, 390, 525, and etc
4. Install driver version 470 using `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470`. I should mention that nvidia website says driver version 535 pic (was't grayed out at the time) --> [for my gpu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPea3.png)
5. Did `sudo reboot`
6. Logged into ubuntu again and checked Additional Drivers (driver installed fine since it was ticked) (was't grayed out at the time) [470](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmoAL.png)

At this moment multiple problems occured! Note I dont have CUDA installed yet!

7. `nvidia-smi` returned `NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.`
8. I installed `sudo apt install nvtop`, but `nvtop` returns `No GPU to monitor.`

Now it becomes weird

9. Installed CUDA `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit nvidia-cuda-toolkit-gcc`, `nvcc --version` 11.5

However, step 9 somehow "removed" nvidia utils. When I run `nvidia-smi` again it returns:

```
Command 'nvidia-smi' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-390         # version 390.157-0ubuntu0.22.04.2, or
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-418-server  # version 418.226.00-0ubuntu5~0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-450-server  # version 450.248.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-470         # version 470.199.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-470-server  # version 470.199.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-525         # version 525.125.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-525-server  # version 525.125.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-510-server  # version 510.47.03-0ubuntu3
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-510         # version 510.108.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-515         # version 515.105.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-515-server  # version 515.105.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-530         # version 530.41.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-535         # version 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
```

I tried to install `sudo apt install nvidia-utils-470`. It got installed but it removed my CUDA, if I run `nvcc --version` something like "nvcc command not found". This is a deathloop that I got stuck in.

10. Now when I try to check Additional Drivers everything is grayed out except this --> [additional drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHx2z.png)

I found this post, but I'm not sure if it will work + it is kinda unclear to me ([Ubuntu 22.04 cannot install nvidia-utils-515 and nvidia-cuda-toolkit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424400/ubuntu-22-04-cannot-install-nvidia-utils-515-and-nvidia-cuda-toolkit))

Edit:

ed1) I don't have `cuda` folder in `/usr/local/` but `nvcc` works

ed2) I tried installing driver version 535 yesterday. Ended up re-installing ubuntu.

ed3) Kernel version 5.19.0-46-generic

> I found this post, but I'm not sure if it will work + it is kinda unclear to me ([Ubuntu 22.04 cannot install nvidia-utils-515 and nvidia-cuda-toolkit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424400/ubuntu-22-04-cannot-install-nvidia-utils-515-and-nvidia-cuda-toolkit))

ed4) Tried the link above, did not help!

ed5) I tried to install ubuntu 20.04 with 5.15.0-76-generic. I followed same steps, nothing works. Right now I suspect that it might be because I have 2 GPUs on my laptop (Asus ROG strix g15 G15RC).

- First. AMD ATI 06:00.0 Device 1681
- Second. NVIDIA 01:00.0 NVIDIA Corporation Device 25a2 (Interesting that in Ubuntu 20.04 system does not see what NVIDIA GPU model I have)

Comment: Are you using kernel 5.15.0 or 6.1.0 to which Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS just was upgraded to? It seems that many have problems with the 6.x kernel and Nvidia drivers.

Comment: @w-sky 5.19.0-46-generic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was solved!

Note that I installed Ubuntu 20.04 because of the kernel problem in Ubuntu 22.04!

In my laptop I have 2 GPUs (hybrid GPU)

I noticed that NVIDIA X Server Setting was not displaying any of my GPUs. So, I started solving that problem, and it happened that found of my hybrid GPU

1. `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470`
2. `sudo reboot`
3. `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`
4. then I disable "Secure Boot" in BIOS settings

Done!